# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'trailing_points' referenced before assignment - its a lie

Tags: python, debugging

This is the code fragment:

```
leading_points = []
trailing_points = []  # <---****
trailing_start = None
for dx in range(counts[break_up]):
    x = (starts[break_up] + dx) % max_x
    ys = line[x]
    if ys[keep] is None:
        if trailing_start is None:
            leading_points.append(ys[break_up])
        else:
            trailing_points.append(ys[break_up])
    else:
        # found the merge point, switch ends
        trailing_start = x
# insert edge residues if they are long enough
if len(leading_points) >= MIN_HORIZONTAL_EDGE_LENGTH:
    # insert leading points
    ring_edges.append([starts[break_up], leading_points])
if len(trailing_points) > MIN_HORIZONTAL_EDGE_LENGTH:
    # insert trailing points
    ring_edges.append([trailing_start, trailing_points])  # <---****
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dave/precious/fellsafe/fellsafe-image/source/experiments/diy.py", line 597, in scan
    results = scan.decode_targets()
  File "/home/dave/precious/fellsafe/fellsafe-image/source/experiments/scan.py", line 3635, in decode_targets
    targets, labels = self._find_codes()
  File "/home/dave/precious/fellsafe/fellsafe-image/source/experiments/scan.py", line 3593, in _find_codes
    digits, reason = self._find_best_digits(digits, extent)
  File "/home/dave/precious/fellsafe/fellsafe-image/source/experiments/scan.py", line 2162, in _find_best_digits
    boxes, reason = self._find_data_boxes(extent, digits, copies)  # ToDo: HACK
  File "/home/dave/precious/fellsafe/fellsafe-image/source/experiments/scan.py", line 2960, in _find_data_boxes
    ring_edges.append([trailing_start, trailing_points])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'trailing_points' referenced before assignment
```

This is python 3.10.7 and debugging in Jetbrains PyCharm Professional on Linux Manjaro.
Can anyone explain why I'm getting that obviously incorrect error?

Comment: what happens if you define the list as [1] or something else? trailing_start may also be causing the issue. In my experience, if you get an error that you know is false, it means some part of the surrounding code has a bug.

Comment: It would be useful if you could include the entire *_find_data_boxes* function in your question

Comment: The error is only thrown when running under the debugger, run normally its fine, there are no 'bugs'. The error complained about is referring to a variable that is used nowhere else so showing the whole function will provide no new information. The error (and others of a similar 'wtf' nature) is inconsistent, sometimes it happens, sometime not, no pattern I can discern. I've come to the conclusion its a problem with the Jetbrains debugger interface, there are various options that can be changed which change the effects, but no option gets rid of them all. Its annoying as it disrupts debugging.